# What is this B Symbol in black and how do I search for it in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, extended-ascii

I am formatting a csv file in Notepad++ and inserting CR and LF so every line is separate but there is a B in the black symbol box shown here:

[image]

that is in some of the lines and I can't find anything about it or how to search for it so I can remove it with the replace function.

Comment: Can you please link a sample file?

Comment: Copy that character into another tab then use the command (from one of the menus) convert to hex. Look up the code in an ASCII table.

Answer (score 6):

Everything that is in a black box in Notepad++ by default is an [ASCII Control Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) - from the Notepad++ source code ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus)), we see that the following ASCII Control Characters are used in Notepad++:

```
static const char *ControlCharacterString(unsigned char ch) noexcept {
    const char * const reps[] = {
        "NUL", "SOH", "STX", "ETX", "EOT", "ENQ", "ACK", "BEL",
        "BS", "HT", "LF", "VT", "FF", "CR", "SO", "SI",
        "DLE", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "NAK", "SYN", "ETB",
        "CAN", "EM", "SUB", "ESC", "FS", "GS", "RS", "US"
    };
...
}
```

What every ASCII control character means can be found in the the [Control Character Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#cite_ref-1), if you are interested.

As you can see, a `B` control character does not exist. This therefore leads me to believe that what you had was `BS`, with the `S` being chopped off for some reason.

To remove the `BS` control character from your text, you would need to replace `\x08` with an empty string.

**Bonus:**

To replicate, some character sequences to get Control Characters:

```
~ Shift + Esc = (ESC)
~ Ctrl + E = (ENQ)
~ Ctrl + R = (DC2)
~ Ctrl + Pause\Break = (ETX)
~ Ctrl + Shift + Y = (EM)
~ Ctrl + Shift + W = (ETB)
~ Ctrl + Shift + O = (SI)
~ Ctrl + Shift + A = (SOH)
~ Ctrl + Shift + D = (EOT)
~ Ctrl + Shift + G = (BEL)
~ Ctrl + Shift + H = (BS)
~ Ctrl + Shift + Z = (SUB)
~ Ctrl + Shift + X = (CAN)
~ Ctrl + Shift + C = (ETX)
~ Ctrl + Shift + v = (SYN)
~ Ctrl + Shift + B = (STX)
~ Ctrl + Shift + N = (SO)
~ Ctrl + Shift + 6 + (RS)
~ Ctrl + Shift + -(Dash) = (US)
```

Comment: To search for `\x08` (BS), `\x1B` (ESC), need to select "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0)" under Search Mode.